# Source Code analysis tools available?

Tags: php, vulnerability, source-code, whitebox

In the near future I have to check the source code of a web application on security vulnerabilities. The web application mainly consists of PHP files and contains more than 300 files.
Do you know programs that can help me with the security analysis of the source code?

Comment: Is the software closed source?

Comment: Yes the software is closed source

Answer (score 2):

For PHP, you can consider tools such as SecureAssist (by Synopsys). Its decently comprehensive and helps find security related vulnerabilities.

Other options include tools such as RIPS.

More  information can be found on the Owasp static analysis tools page:

https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Source_Code_Analysis_Tools

Answer (score 1):

Use [sqlmap](http://sqlmap.org/) to automatically test for SQL Injections

Another great tool I enjoy using is [Taint](https://github.com/laruence/taint). If you can somehow run those files locally, this will come in handy :)

Comment: Sqlmap is a black box testing tool, i dont have the permissions for black box testing:/

Comment: "i dont have the permissions for black box testing", not even on a local clone of the system with a cloned, or test, database?